# Passing data to parent after login from service

Tags: angular, angular5

I have an application in which there is a dropdown in app(main).component.html.

```
  <li class="dropdown" *ngIf="sessionService.isLoggedIn || sessionService.isFirstTimeLogin">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="hidden-md">Select Company</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li *ngFor="let company of companyList">
        <a (click)="selectCompany(company)">{{company.CompanyName}}</a>
      </li>
      <!--<li><a><i class="dropdown-icon fa fa-envelope"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Messages</a></li>-->
    </ul>
  </li>
```

The variable `companyList` which is looped for adding data to options in select is getting data from service in app.component.ts.

```
getCompanyList() {
    //this.loaderService.showLoader();
    this.masterService.getCompanyList()
        .subscribe(
        (response) => {
            this.companyList = response.data.recordset;
            this.loaderService.hideLoader();
        },
        (error) => {
            this.loaderService.hideLoader();
        })
}
```

which is calling on ngOnInit.

```
ngOnInit() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("isLoggedIn")){
        this.getCompanyList();
    }
}
```

The problem is after login the dashboard page getting opened but dropdown is in app.component.html. So the data is not populated first on component load but when I refresh the page the dropdown get populated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, When child component loads it'll execute `ngOnInit()` which will trigger an event to the parent component and execute `next()` of the parent component.

Child Component

```
@Output() callparent = new EventEmitter < string > ();
ngOnInit() {
    this.callparent.emit('some data');
}
```

Parent Component HTML

```
<div class="centered-content">
    <child-component (callparent)="next($event)"></child-component >
</div>
```

Parent Component

```
next(event) {
    console.log('Hi From parent');
}
```

Comment: How can we use the for loop on the data coming from child to create a dropdown. In you case even if the data is coming using child how we can add this to parent

Answer (score 0):

You call the function on `ngOnInit`.The function subscribes to the observable and returns
Calling a function which subscribes won't work  since the subscribtion is on the function's **stack** and not on **component's memory

Answer (score 0):

This is not a template issue or load order, instead, no one is watching this variable `companyList` for you for free in angular now.

Couple of ways to fix it,

**Service**. Via `observable`, if `login` is a service, you can publish an `observable`, ex. `$companies`, so that whoever is using this service can subscribe to it. This way your display logic can be somewhere else. Tutorial: https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/observables/using_observables.html

```
this.login.$companies.subscribe(userList => ...);
```

**Component**. Make sure `companyList` is a `@Input()` variable written in your display component, ex. `companyListComponent`. Angular will watch it for you when `companyList` reference is getting modified. Then you can include it via `<company-list [items]="companyList" />`

```
export class companyListComponent {  
    @Input() items;  
}
```

Either way, the idea is that you need to make a reusable stuff out of your logic first, which happens to be a good thing here.